# Inserting a new <ul> in a selected <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I have this as a test harness:

```
<html>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("li").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("nodeid");
            var path = window.location + "/SelectNode/" + id;

            $.getJSON(path, function (data, status) {
                alert(id + " : " + data);
                //$("#" + id).text("<ul><li>" + data + "</li></ul>");
            });

        });

    });


</script>
<title>JS Test</title>
<head>
    JS Test</head>
<body>
    <div">
        <ul>
            <li nodeid="1">item 1</li>
            <li nodeid="2">item 2</li>
            <li nodeid="3">item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to add a new child list to the 'clicked' li.  For the life of me I can't figure out the syntax of injecting html after the specific li item clicked.  The intention is to add an entire

```
<ul>
<li>injected item</li>
</ul>
```

after the the selected li.  The commented out bit is my feeble attempt at it.  It goes without saying that I am a jQuery beginner.  I am throughly confused after reading the docs so need some people interaction to straigten me out here...

Comment: You should be using the native "id" instead of "nodeid", then you can use $('#'+nodeid) instead of using an attribute.

Comment: Also, IDs cannot start with numbers.

Comment: Local architect prefers not to use id, as it has other meaning associated with it.

Comment: The use a class name or the standardized "data-" attribute (data-nodeid), then you can use $(...).data('nodeid')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, is the `nodeid` attribute valid HTML? I don't think so. Use `data-nodeid`, this would be valid HTML5. (Why don't you use a normal `id`? You are mixing `nodeid` and `id`. Anyway, it's possible with `nodeid`. read on.)

If you want to add HTML code you can't use `.text()`. There are many ways to add HTML code, this is an example with `.append`: http://jsfiddle.net/Vxaeb/1/

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(this).append('<ul><li>injected item</li></ul>');
});
```

(Just an example)

You get the `data-nodeid` with `var id = $(this).attr("data-nodeid");`.
Access the element with `$('li[data-nodeid="'+id+'"]')`.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li data-nodeid="1">item 1</li>
        <li data-nodeid="2">item 2</li>
        <li data-nodeid="3">item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Full JS:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-nodeid");
    var path = window.location + "/SelectNode/" + id;

    $.getJSON(path, function (data, status) {
        alert(id + " : " + data);
        $('li[data-nodeid="'+id+'"]').append('<ul><li>'+data+'</li></ul>');
    });
});
```

Here a jsFiddle with your code AND `nodeid` (as you mentioned you needed that) AND valid HTML5:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vxaeb/3/

Comment: this works fine... except $(this) does not select properly from within the .getJSON function.  Outside that, it works fine... but the data is not available, since it retrieved from a JsonResult method in my controller.

Comment: You should `data-nodeid` because `nodeid` is not valid HTML. there is no attribute called `nodeid` in HTML. `data-nodeid` is valid HTML, by prepending `data-` you can use your own attribute names. that has nothing to do with your `.getJSON`! 

Take a look at my updated fiddle/post.
 http://jsfiddle.net/Vxaeb/3/

Comment: thanks for that.  The single-double quotes syntax worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you have no element with that id on the page. second of all, you are trying to add html to the LI element, not plain text so you should use `.html()`

```
$("li[nodeid=" + id + "]").html("<ul><li>" + data + "</li></ul>");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('<li>item 4</li>').insertAfter('#ABC')` would work, if you had a `LI` with an ID of "ABC". If you use regular IDs in your HTML this will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert data **after** your selected li element, use jQuery's [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) function:

```
$('.selected').after('<p>Test</p>');
```

If you want to insert data **inside** your selected li element, use jQuery's [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function.

```
$('.selected').html('<p>Test</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).append('<ul><li>xxx</li></ul>');        
});
```

[Click here for a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P67aY/)